# Defining custom function/property inside anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-types

I want to define my property and function in anonymous class as under

```
ExistingExtendableJavaClass aClass = new ExistingExtendableJavaClass() {
         public String someProperty;

         public String getMyProperty() { return someProperty }
});
```

But then these calls don't work

```
aClass.someProperty // not accessible
aClass.getMyProperty() // not accessible
```

I know because `ExistingExtendableJavaClass` doesn't have these, but then my anonymous has these. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on *why* you need it to be like that?
The first thing coming to my mind is to define an interface with those properties and methods and the cast your object to it.

Comment: Because there is an anonymous defined inside a class. This anonymous classes uses members of the outer class to do lot of things. Now a functionality is needed for Outer class to do know if the function inside the anonymous classes were invoked or not. There can be many solutions to this, I have solved this by defining properties in outer class and setting them to value in anonymous class. But @rzwitserloot looks good to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are accessible just fine:

```
new ExistingExtendable() {
    public void foo() {}
}.foo();
```

works great.

But if you write:

```
ExistingExtendable x = new ExistingExtendable() {
    public void foo() {}
};
x.foo();
```

That does not work. For the same reason this doesn't work:

```
Object o = new String();
o.toLowerCase(); // nope
```

The problem is that your anonymous class has no name, thus, you cannot denote its type. We can fix the string example by replacing `Object o` with `String o`, but there is no `String` equivalent.

**However, that is the point of an anonymous inner class**.

If you want these to be denotable, then you don't want an anonymous inner class. Asking: "I want an anonymous inner class, but I want the new members I declared in them to be accessible" is like asking: "I want a circle, but.. with corners".

You can make method local inner classes, and now you have names:

```
public void example(String x) {
    class IAmAMethodLocalClass extends ExistingExtendableJavaClass {
        String someProperty; // making them public is quite useless.

        String foo() {
            System.out.println(x); // you can access x here.
        }
    }

    IAmAMethodLocalClass hello = new IAmAMethodLocalClass();
    hello.someProperty = "It works!";
}
```

an anonymous inner class is the same as this method local class thing, except it avoids naming the type. In this case, you *NEED* that name, thus, you can't use the anonymous inner class construct.

Comment: Wow ! It does the job for me. Why did I not think of this.